# Send parameters by using GET method in REST server

Tags: c#, rest, visual-c++, casablanca, cpprest-sdk

I have simple REST server GET method:

```
    public class PersonController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/Person
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
...
}
```

It works fine with cpp rest client:

```
http_response httpResponse = httpClient.request(methods::GET).get();
    if (httpResponse.status_code() == status_codes::OK)
    {
        wstring output = httpResponse.extract_utf16string().get();
        wcout << output << endl;
    }
```

I decided to pass some parameters while do `GET` and have done changes in:

client:

```
http_response httpResponse = httpClient.request(methods::GET,L"HELLO").get();
```

server:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get([FromBody]string value)
```

`[FromBody]string value` I have coppyed from `POST` method and was expecting it will work.

Unfortunately client call has no response from server side now. Can I use `GET` with parameters in general? What I do wrong?

UPD:

I have removed `[FromBody]`, but still have response 400 from client side

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get(string value)
```

Comment: Remove that `[FromBody]` Get Requests have not Body

Comment: I have removed [FromBody], but this not solved the problem

Comment: try to put `[HttpGet]`,
        `[Route("Get/{value}")]`attributes on your action.